# How to fetch array value having String Key using Angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an array and want to fetch some values from array which has Strings as key.Please suggest how can i retrieve those values from array have string as key.

Code for Controller is:

```
var ultColumn=undefined;
$scope.ultColm="Attained Age";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
ultColumn=ultrowCellData[i][$scope.ultColmn];//This is not working
}//ultrowCellData contains the array
```

Please suggest how to get the value of key "Attained Age"

[image]

Comment: JSON keys always treating as a `string`. So, we can not differentiate the data type of keys but values can be `Number,String,Boolean,Array,Object,Whitespace,null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.forEach();` For example:

```
angular.forEach(yourArray, function(value, key){
  if(typeof key === 'string'){
     console.log("Your result is here :", value);
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If screenshot which you provided shows data included in ultrowCellData then it is not an array but map - `var something = ultrowCellData['Attained Age ']` will assign value `28` to `something`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten a space at the end of your key, on line 2.

Try `Attained Age<space>` instead of `Attained Age` (replace `<space>` with an actual space).

Notice, though, that this is a non-standard use for an Array, as arrays usually use only numbers as keys.

if at all possible, try using an `Object` instead.